# How to run Python packages on Windows?

Tags: python, pip, package

I have installed this package https://bitbucket.org/lukaszlaba/dxf2svg/src/master/ with pip from python.org.

`pip show dxf2svg` shows me the location : `Location: c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages`

But if I do : `dxf2svg myfile.dxf` the command is not recognized by the windows cli...
I already add Python folder locations in the PATH env variable so what is the problem ?

[image]

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment in which you installed this app using pip? Try running it while being in the virtual environment.

Comment: No, I didn't set up because it was mentionned as optional in the manual. What the benefits of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
python -m dxf2svg myfile.dxf
```